# Save value computed in the loop and delete it

Tags: output

I am using For loop to calculate a value $z$ in every cycle. I would like to create a text file, save the current value $z$ in this file and afterwards delete the value from *Mathematica*'s memory. I would also like to do it as fast as possible.

Example of my loop:

```
For[x=0,x<=1,x=x+0.5;z=Exp[x^2]]
```

Comment: `For[]` and similar loops are very inefficient in Mathematica. Why don't you add what are you trying to achieve instead of focusing in the function you want to use.

Comment: See for example http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18396/193

Comment: do you really need to `Write` in the loop? It would almost certainly be faster to save the data and write it out all at once.

Answer (score 1):

First of all **avoid using `For` loop** better (and faster) use `Do` instead.

```
stream = OpenWrite["c:\\1.txt"];
Do[
  z = Exp[x^2];
  Write[stream, z]
  , {x, 0, 100000, 0.5}];
Close[stream];
```

PS: it is best to avoid cycles for functional analog